# What is the correct way to use/create a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error:

```
NameError in GamesController#create
uninitialized constant User::UsersGame
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

Which is confusing because I don't know why it is referencing UsersGame instead of UserGame...

I've tried renaming things, taking the new method out (still confuses my why new and create are both needed but I think I understand they both need to be there), and messing with my migrations to make sure I have the correct tables, but I can't get it working.  The users class works by itself with devise so I don't think that can be a problem.  Anyways here are the relevant files below.

users_games.rb in models as a join table

```
class UserGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end
```

user.rb in models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_games
  has_many :games, :through => :users_games
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

game.rb in models

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_games
  has_many :users, :through => :users_games
#  has_many :turns, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :name, :creator
end
```

Comment: Can you post the line number in which this error occurs?

Comment: Its a good idea to name your class as UserGame.

Comment: why you use plural on your model 'UsersGames'?.

Comment: do I change it anywhere besides the users_games.rb file? also updated with the line

Comment: actually you dont need users_games.rb at all, rather delete it and replace  

`has_many :users_games`
`has_many :users, :through => :users_games` 

to 

`has_and_belongs_to_many :games, join_table: 'users_games'`
in user.rb

Comment: do i need to specify a column for game_id in the users table? and user_id in the games table?

Comment: or after adding this association do I have to do any sort of migration? if so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of `has_many through`.

`has_and_belongs_to_many :games , join_table: 'users_games'`

if you change your join table to games_users then just use:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :games`

and please follow this:

[nested form & habtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026002)

For more about habtm (to avoid duplicate entry) :

[Rails nested form on HABTM: how to prevent duplicate entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954411)

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah it's just a join table

Comment: if i switch it to UsersGame then what do i say in the has_many line?

Comment: if its only join table then you need to change the association from 

`has_many :users_games`
 `has_many :users, :through => :users_games`
 to 
`has_and_belongs_to_many :games , join_table: 'users_games'` 

and please follow this: stackoverflow.com/questions/3026002/nested-form-habtm to create/manage habtm association

Comment: it seems to have gotten me past my last issue, but now I'm getting the error 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in GamesController#show

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: games_users: SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "games_users" ON "games"."id" = "games_users"."game_id" WHERE "games_users"."user_id" = 5 AND "games"."id" = ? LIMIT 1

Comment: Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:16:in `show'

Comment: It looks like it actually creates things now, but has trouble with the show.  When testing it on the console it looks like it doesn't understand the association when using `g = game.first` then `g.users` trhows the same sql3 error

Comment: make sure your association is like:
`has_and_belongs_to_many :games , join_table: 'users_games'`.
You have to mention the join_table here as your table name is users_games. for join table the convention is  alphabetically sorted pluralize models joint with under_score. i.e. games_users in your case

Comment: do i then have to create the table via a migration?

Comment: not mandatory, just use join_table option as I mentioned in previous comment. 
But if you  want you can rename your table to games_users (using a migration) then `has_and_belongs_to_many :games` will be enough.

Comment: im a little confused.  if the convention is games_users then why do i have to migrate it to that?  why would rails create it the other way around?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32047/discussion-between-muntasim-and-tmp)